# How to setup Apache Reverse Proxy with wild card regex on Location tag?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I need to setup a reverse proxy for apache so it works like this:

```
http://path1/serverA/xxx  --> http://localhost:82/xxx
http://path2/serverA/xxx  --> http://localhost:82/xxx
http://path3/serverA/xxx  --> http://localhost:82/xxx
```

The path1, path2, path3 contains "/" for example path1=some/paths. I am just using path1,2,3 to be short in here.

It works if I setup like this:

```
   <Location /path1/serverA>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:82/ smax=50 ttl=120
        ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:82/j
   </Location> 
   <Location /path2/serverA>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:82/ smax=50 ttl=120
        ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:82/j
   </Location> 
   <Location /path3/serverA>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:82/ smax=50 ttl=120
        ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:82/j
   </Location>
```

But it is quite verbose. I saw apache documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location shows that Location can take regex expression. So I use it but it doesn't work. My config is

```
   <Location ~ "/(path1|path2|path2)/serverA">
        ProxyPass http://localhost:82/ smax=50 ttl=120
        ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:82/j
   </Location>
```

Can you show me where I missed?

Answer (score 0):

> <Location ~ "/(path1|path2|path2)/serverA">

Do "path1", "path2", or "path3" have any regex special characters in them such as: . - + ( ) $

If so, they would need to be escaped with a: \

Also, if the paths (1,2,3) start or end with a "/", you need to remove the corresponding "/" in the regex string, otherwise you are matching against "//".

You can also try using this instead:

```
<LocationMatch ^/(path1|path2|path3)/serverA>
```